# How to report a +/- standard error for logarithmic data?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, standard-error, error, logarithm, error-propagation

I have some data $y$ which varies logarithmically which I am fitting with MCMC methods. It makes more sense to do my analysis in the logarithmic space $z = \mathrm{log}(y)$. As I result, I end up with estimates for my logarithmic data $z$. This results in e.g. a histogram for $z$:

[image]

I can do some statistics on this distribution and get things like the mean and standard deviation. For example, in the histogram above, the mean value of $z$ is $1.11\pm0.06$ where the $\pm$ denotes 1 standard deviation.

However, even though the results are logarithmically distributed, it makes more sense to report values in $y$ units. What is the best way to report error in this case?

Comment: Careful, you've used the terms standard deviation and standard error somewhat interchangeably, but they capture different things (although your question is valid for either one). The value of 0.06 looks too small for the SD from the histogram, I'm guessing it's the SE.

Comment: Also note that if these are physical quantities, your choice of units affects the results.

Answer (score 0):

if you still have your MCMC chain with samples of $z$, then $\exp(z)$ will be samples of $y$ so you can calculate distributional properties (such as variances) and build credible intervals from that.